# onChange doesn't fire when using ListboxComponent in MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
     <Autocomplete
        options={options}
        fullWidth
        renderInput={renderOptionValue}
        onChange={(e, value) => {
          // @ts-ignore
          console.log(e.target, value.title);
        }}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => getUserFullName(option)}
        PopperComponent={(props) => <S.DropDownPopper {...props} />}
        ListboxComponent={() => (
          <FixedSizeList
            height={400}
            itemCount={options.length}
            itemData={[...options]}
            itemSize={36}
            overscanCount={5}
            width="100%"
          >
            {(props) => <ListItem {...props} />}
          </FixedSizeList>
        )}
      />
```

I tried passing onClick to the `ListItem` component - does not work

I removed the `ListboxComponent` component and onClick works, maybe I should pass ref or i don't know.

I use `material UI` with `react-window`